# Create hollow intersecting tubes

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm trying to create some hollow intersecting tubes as is hopefully clearly demonstrated in these two screenshots.

In this one, I've selected the internal parts that are hollow. Note that the holes meet in the middle; the same internal space is accessible from all three holes.
[image: Screenshot of hollow tubes.]
There's a Suzanne on the other side to clearly show the hole.
[image: Screenshot of hollow tubes!]

The problem is that I haven't found any good way of making tubes like my example above. I used five boolean modifiers, some undoing and redoing, and a lot of manual removing of geometry to get the above, and I really think there are better ways to do this... Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In User Preferences search for the "Pipe Joints" addon and enable it.

[image]

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and go to *Mesh > Pipe Joints > Pipe Y-Joint*.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Pipe Joints is now part of the Extra Objects Addon in the *Add Mesh* category
[image]

And can be accessed through Add>Mesh>Mechanical>Pipe Joints

[image]

You can control the shape and angle of the joint by using the tab on the left side of the 3D view.

[image]

To add some thickness use a solidify modifier.

[image]

Comment: Related is this video that show different ways for cutting holes. (It should be required viewing for anyone learning blender)http://vimeo.com/68844586

Comment: Thanks, that is a _very_ useful video for a beginner like me.