# Merge two cylinder into a joint

Tags: modeling, mesh

How would I go about merging two cylinders in order to achieve a result similar to the joint in the highlighted part in this image?
[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: You can also use the [Pipe Joints](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12081/create-hollow-intersecting-tubes/12082#12082) addon , choose pipe elbow and set the angle to 90 degree: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbTba.gif

Comment: Also related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42591/how-to-aproach-the-modeling-of-duct-work-piping-wiring/42594#42594

Comment: Consider modeling it from a curve. See this Duarte Farrajota Ramos 's solution here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/how-to-make-beveled-90-degree-corners-on-a-curve-better