# Connection of beveled curves

Tags: bevel, bezier-curves

I have a bezier curve with some bevel. In some places I need to have more than two outgoing lines from one vertex, so curve splitted for several segments. Is there any way to make connections looks better?

Currently it looks as you can seen:
[image]

But I need something like this:
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57284/it-is-possible-to-extrude-a-curve-to-two-directions/57288

Comment: Hi :). This thread could help with the T joint: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/12081/